# In Gimp how to take the brightest value of each color channel for every pixel?

Tags: gimp, rgb, pixel, filter

In Gimp I want to generate a gray scale image of a RGB image defined by this per-pixel formula: `value_xy = max(R_xy, G_xy, B_xy)`.

I didn't find a builtin feature so I wonder if there's some generic filter out there where I can operate on a per-pixel basis by just defining some formula.

Is there something like this already? Would I have to write my own filter for Gimp?

Answer (score 3):

No need for specific filter...

- `Color>Components>Decompose` and use RGB Model, you get a grayscale image where each layer is one of the RGB channels of the original image
- Set the top two layers to `Lighten only` mode.

[image]

Comment: I've changed the title to match your answer :) This is what I've been looking for - but since you seem to know Gimp - do you know the answer to the original Question? Is there a builtin way (or an existing filter) which allows me to calculate color values with functional expressions on a per-pixel basis?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Since you are usually dealing with millions of pixels, this is best done with a compiled language, in other words in a C plugin. The other (and likely more palatable option) is to write a filter for the [GMIC processor](http://gmic.eu/gimp.shtml), that works as a Gimp plugin or as command-line processor. But you may also find frameworks to do this kind of job in a command line program/script. For instance, there is the [`pillow` module for Python](https://python-pillow.org/).